# Material SVGs exported from sketch not showing up in client's browser, but fine in my browser - how to test?

Tags: css, svg, browser, google-material-icons, sketch-3

I'm assuming it's an export issue. Trying to figure out how to recreate the issue - any one experience this? Solutions also welcome. Will try re-exporting from Illustrator.

here are some troublesome SVGs (material icons):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="18px" height="19px" viewBox="0 0 18 19" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs></defs>
<g id="R02" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" font-family="material" font-size="24" font-weight="normal">
    <g id="Live-Event-03---Account-Menu" transform="translate(-1160.000000, -158.000000)" fill="#98A4AE">
        <g id="menu" transform="translate(1124.000000, 56.000000)">
            <g id="item" transform="translate(33.000000, 100.000000)">
                <text id="exit_to_app---material">
                    <tspan x="0" y="20"></tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="27px" height="23px" viewBox="0 0 27 23" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<!-- Generator: Sketch 50.2 (55047) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
<title>send - material</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g id="R02" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" font-family="material" font-size="30" font-weight="normal">
    <g id="Modal-05---Share" transform="translate(-477.000000, -395.000000)" fill="#98A4AE">
        <g id="modal" transform="translate(435.000000, 376.000000)">
            <g id="header">
                <text id="send---material">
                    <tspan x="40" y="41"></tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

Here is a SVG that was viewed correctly (custom):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="56px" height="56px" viewBox="0 0 56 56" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="icon/account-white" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <path d="M28,45.256 C30.8373475,45.256 33.5066542,44.5466738 36.008,43.128 C38.4346788,41.8213268 40.4319922,40.0106782 42,37.696 C41.9626665,36.2773262 41.0853419,34.9706726 39.368,33.776 C37.8746592,32.767995 35.9706782,31.9466698 33.656,31.312 C31.5653229,30.7519972 29.6706752,30.472 27.972,30.472 C26.2733248,30.472 24.3786771,30.7519972 22.288,31.312 C19.9733218,31.9466698 18.0880073,32.767995 16.632,33.776 C14.9146581,34.9706726 14.0373335,36.2773262 14,37.696 C15.5680078,40.0106782 17.5653212,41.8213268 19.992,43.128 C22.5306794,44.5466738 25.199986,45.256 28,45.256 Z M28,12.104 C26.7679938,12.104 25.6106721,12.4213302 24.528,13.056 C23.4453279,13.6906698 22.5866698,14.5493279 21.952,15.632 C21.3173302,16.7146721 21,17.8719938 21,19.104 C21,20.3360062 21.3173302,21.4933279 21.952,22.576 C22.5866698,23.6586721 23.4453279,24.5173302 24.528,25.152 C25.6106721,25.7866698 26.7679938,26.104 28,26.104 C29.2320062,26.104 30.3893279,25.7866698 31.472,25.152 C32.5546721,24.5173302 33.4133302,23.6586721 34.048,22.576 C34.6826698,21.4933279 35,20.3360062 35,19.104 C35,17.8719938 34.6826698,16.7146721 34.048,15.632 C33.4133302,14.5493279 32.5546721,13.6906698 31.472,13.056 C30.3893279,12.4213302 29.2320062,12.104 28,12.104 Z M28,5.104 C32.2560213,5.104 36.1946486,6.16798936 39.816,8.296 C43.3253509,10.3120101 46.0879899,13.0746491 48.104,16.584 C50.2320106,20.2053514 51.296,24.1439787 51.296,28.4 C51.296,32.6560213 50.2320106,36.5946486 48.104,40.216 C46.0879899,43.7253509 43.3253509,46.4879899 39.816,48.504 C36.1946486,50.6320106 32.2560213,51.696 28,51.696 C23.7439787,51.696 19.8053514,50.6320106 16.184,48.504 C12.6746491,46.4506564 9.91201008,43.6693509 7.896,40.16 C5.76798936,36.5386486 4.704,32.6186878 4.704,28.4 C4.704,24.1813122 5.76798936,20.2613514 7.896,16.64 C9.9493436,13.1306491 12.7306491,10.3493436 16.24,8.296 C19.8613514,6.16798936 23.7813122,5.104 28,5.104 Z" id="account_circle---material" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
</g>
```

Comment: Can you add some code or at least a link to your SVG?

Comment: @enxaneta code added, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The svgs had a lot of transforms going to and fro which I deleted. Also I could have eliminated some of the nested `<g>` elements, but maybe you putted them there for some reason.
Also in the CSS I've putted a border to the SVG so that you can see that there is a white space between the icon and the border of the svg canvas. Should it have been for me I would have eliminated that space, but again: you may need it. I hope this helps.

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg width="18px" height="19px" viewBox="0 2 18 19" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs></defs>
<g id="R02" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" font-family="material" font-size="24" font-weight="normal">
    <g id="Live-Event-03---Account-Menu"  fill="#98A4AE">
        <g id="menu">
            <g id="item">
                <text id="exit_to_app---material">
                    <tspan y="20"></tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>

<svg width="27px" height="23px" viewBox="0 20 27 23" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<!-- Generator: Sketch 50.2 (55047) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
<title>send - material</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g id="R02" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" font-family="material" font-size="30" font-weight="normal">
    <g id="Modal-05---Share"  fill="#98A4AE">
        <g id="modal" >
            <g id="header">
                <text id="send---material">
                    <tspan y="41"></tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
  
<svg width="56px" height="56px" viewBox="0 0 56 56" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="icon" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <path d="M28,45.256 C30.8373475,45.256 33.5066542,44.5466738 36.008,43.128 C38.4346788,41.8213268 40.4319922,40.0106782 42,37.696 C41.9626665,36.2773262 41.0853419,34.9706726 39.368,33.776 C37.8746592,32.767995 35.9706782,31.9466698 33.656,31.312 C31.5653229,30.7519972 29.6706752,30.472 27.972,30.472 C26.2733248,30.472 24.3786771,30.7519972 22.288,31.312 C19.9733218,31.9466698 18.0880073,32.767995 16.632,33.776 C14.9146581,34.9706726 14.0373335,36.2773262 14,37.696 C15.5680078,40.0106782 17.5653212,41.8213268 19.992,43.128 C22.5306794,44.5466738 25.199986,45.256 28,45.256 Z M28,12.104 C26.7679938,12.104 25.6106721,12.4213302 24.528,13.056 C23.4453279,13.6906698 22.5866698,14.5493279 21.952,15.632 C21.3173302,16.7146721 21,17.8719938 21,19.104 C21,20.3360062 21.3173302,21.4933279 21.952,22.576 C22.5866698,23.6586721 23.4453279,24.5173302 24.528,25.152 C25.6106721,25.7866698 26.7679938,26.104 28,26.104 C29.2320062,26.104 30.3893279,25.7866698 31.472,25.152 C32.5546721,24.5173302 33.4133302,23.6586721 34.048,22.576 C34.6826698,21.4933279 35,20.3360062 35,19.104 C35,17.8719938 34.6826698,16.7146721 34.048,15.632 C33.4133302,14.5493279 32.5546721,13.6906698 31.472,13.056 C30.3893279,12.4213302 29.2320062,12.104 28,12.104 Z M28,5.104 C32.2560213,5.104 36.1946486,6.16798936 39.816,8.296 C43.3253509,10.3120101 46.0879899,13.0746491 48.104,16.584 C50.2320106,20.2053514 51.296,24.1439787 51.296,28.4 C51.296,32.6560213 50.2320106,36.5946486 48.104,40.216 C46.0879899,43.7253509 43.3253509,46.4879899 39.816,48.504 C36.1946486,50.6320106 32.2560213,51.696 28,51.696 C23.7439787,51.696 19.8053514,50.6320106 16.184,48.504 C12.6746491,46.4506564 9.91201008,43.6693509 7.896,40.16 C5.76798936,36.5386486 4.704,32.6186878 4.704,28.4 C4.704,24.1813122 5.76798936,20.2613514 7.896,16.64 C9.9493436,13.1306491 12.7306491,10.3493436 16.24,8.296 C19.8613514,6.16798936 23.7813122,5.104 28,5.104 Z" id="account_circle---material" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
</g>
    
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, we were able to solve the issue by exporting through Illustrator. Here is how the newly exported SVG code looked:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 56 56"><defs><style>.a{fill:#98a4ae;}</style></defs><title>sign-out-gray</title><path class="a" d="M44.2964,7a4.5218,4.5218,0,0,1,3.3027,1.4A4.52,4.52,0,0,1,49,11.7036V44.2964a4.7835,4.7835,0,0,1-4.7031,4.7041H11.7041a4.4923,4.4923,0,0,1-3.332-1.4A4.5585,4.5585,0,0,1,7,44.2964V35h4.7041v9.2969H44.2964V11.7036H11.7041V21H7V11.7036A4.5629,4.5629,0,0,1,8.3721,8.3994,4.4919,4.4919,0,0,1,11.7041,7ZM23.52,36.4l5.9922-6.1045H7V25.7036H29.5122L23.52,19.6l3.3042-3.3042L38.5278,28,26.8242,39.7036Z"/></svg>
```